# How to deal with many comments on an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am relatively new in Stackoverflow and this situation happened a few times. I'm not sure how to handle them in order to keep the quality of the post (question & answer).

[PHP headers not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871985/php-headers-not-working)

The original PHP error was `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`, which as far as I know only have one cause. HTTP headers are modified after content was already sent. And in my opinion, the best way to fix is to move the `header()` call before output is actually sent. That was my original answer, and in my opinion the only valid answer. But the discussion started *shifting* in the comments, and I lost control of it. At the end my answer got down-voted and the post was abandoned.

Should I delete my answer, as it is clearly not valid for the question author? Should I edit my answer to reflect the conversation in the comments and offer another alternative that I don't feel is right? Or should I also abandon this post even if the question was perfectly valid and my answer was in my opinion perfectly valid too? Should I down-vote the question to release my frustration?

Comment: Why answer it at all? This question is one of the most duplicated ones in SO. I usually delete my answer when the OP gets help vampiric in the comments when he can't understand me to implement my solution correctly.

Comment: @Esailija I understand your point. But I'm interested to know how to handle that in general.

Comment: If there's a comment discussion spiralling out of control in one of your posts, you can flag for moderation attention and ask for the post to be locked (for an hour, or even a day). Locking will prevent any further comments (and votes, edits).

Comment: From what I see it has turned into a customer support/help desk session... the only way out of it is deletion :D

Comment: @YannisRizos I didn't know there was such thing as a temporary lock. That sounds like a great idea!

Comment: *Related:* [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: _Should I down-vote the question to release my frustration?_  of course not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's a comment discussion spiralling out of control in one of your posts, you can flag for moderation attention and ask for the post to be locked for a short while - your options are an hour, a day and a week.  Locking will prevent any further comments, but also voting, edits and flags on your post. In my experience as a moderator on Programmers, locking for an hour is quite effective in stopping comment wars.

Obviously, locking would be overkill if we are talking about a handful of comments. If that's the case, your best option is to flag those that you feel are flag worthy, stop responding and walk away. If a user keeps pestering you after a while, flag your own post for moderation attention and explain the situation.